# How to check for a substring in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

(Because a (Define) My php file shows a second line). It will have like OK+a empty line

So I would like to make my check so it's like not if responde = OK

but if response contains OK

Full code: http://meepbeta.tk/hotel/minified.js

The line I'm talking about:

```
var b=d.responseText;if(b=="OK"){saved=true;if(!a){var a="http://sunniedaynl.net/client"}showResult('<img src="dissi-editor.png" style="float: left;padding-left: 25px;"><strong>
```

Won't work:

Is there any way to make it like

```
if(b.Contains("OK")) //<--- This doesnt work
```

It doesn't work because of the second line

This is the script it checks:

```
function sendMap(){var a=getExport();asyncAjax("POST","check.php","gamemap="+a+"&doorx="+doorX+"&doory=‌​"+doorY,doChecks,{}
```

Then, it checks for the OK

```
b=d.responseText;if(b=="OK"){saved=true;if(!a){var a="sunniedaynl.net/client";}showResult('<img src="dissi-edit
```

But I want it to check for something that contains OK not just check if the whole text is OK, so it'd even detect it if it was like **OKay32r34**.

Comment: Do you want to check for a line that _contains_ "OK" or a line that _starts_ with "OK"? Also, it's not clear: What do you want to do with a line that is like "OKay32r34"?

Comment: Hi there. I see you put a space in disallowed title phrases in order to escape the question quality filter. That's actually in there for a reason - please try to use question titles that are representative of the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `b.indexOf("OK") === 0`. This ensures that the first two characters of `b` are `"OK"`, matching `"OKay32r34"` but not matching `"rOK"`.

I'd also like to note that `b.Contains` doesn't work because there's no method `Contains` defined, there is however `contains` but it checks for it anywhere in the string. (and thus would match `"NOT OK"`)

Comment: Well, id also like it to check even NOT OK, i just want it to detect if there's OK in that page somewhere

EDIT i tink what u did is fine ima try it now THX :)!

Comment: EDIT: it doesnt work this is the file its checking in: [link](http://secretup.com/uploads/response.png?img=10)[/link]

A part of my PHP script is causing that second line, but its not possible to remove it without it wont work, so i want it to detect the OK from there :/ anny ideas?

Comment: EDIT2: ive seem to insert it wrong somehow :P it didnt save it works like a charm thank you so much :D!!!!!

Comment: @user3641810: if this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the tick mark to the left. It's how we thank people here.

Comment: @user3641810: please let me know here when you've accepted this (or why you aren't accepting) and I'll undownvote the question. Thanks.